# how to make a radius of the circle using python

Tags: python

Here is my code I keep getting errors. Write a program that prompts the user to enter the coordinates of the center and a point on the circle. The program should then output the circle’s radius, diameter, circumference, and area.This is for an intro class to python.

```
def main():    
    x1 = eval(input("enter x1"))
    y1 = eval(input("enter y1"))
    x2 = eval(input("enter x2"))
    y2 = eval(input("enter y2"))
    print((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)*(1/2)

pi = 3.14 
c = float(input("input the circumference of the circle :"))
print("the diameter of the circle with circumference" + str(c) + " is: " + str(2*pi*r))

r = float(input("input the radius of the circle :"))
print("the area of the circle with radius" + str(r) + " is: " + str(pi*r^2))

print("The radius,diameter,circumference,and area")

main()
```

Comment: What errors do you have ?

Comment: `c = float("input the circumference of the circle :")` should be `c = float(input("input the circumference of the circle :"))`, same for `r=`

Comment: my error is that my circumference is giving me error

Comment: Your `print("the diameter of the circle with circumference" + str(c) + " is: " + str(2*pi*r))` statement uses `r' before it is defined.

Comment: There are no less than 4 types of errors with your code, see my answer for a complete list.

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors, both inside and outside the function:

1) You need to convert the input to *numbers*. Change this and the other similar lines:

```
x1 = eval(input("enter x1"))
```

To this:

```
x1 = float(input("enter x1"))
```

2) The `^` operator is not doing what you think, in Python we use `**` as the power operator. And it's better to *return* a value from a function, instead of printing the result. You should replace this line:

```
print((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)^(1/2)
```

With this:

```
return ((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**(1/2)
```

3) You're using `r` before defining it, simply move this line to the first line:

```
r = float("input the radius of the circle :")
```

4) Change this and the other line similar to it:

```
c = float("input the circumference of the circle :")
```

To this:

```
c = float(input("input the circumference of the circle :"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For circle code

- You miss the `input` method, you cannot build a `float` from a string
- the power operator is `**`
- you can't use variable before defining them (here `r`)

```
pi = 3.14
c = float(input("input the circumference of the circle: "))
r = float(input("input the radius of the circle: "))

print("the diameter of the circle with circumference", c, "is:", str(2 * pi * r))
print("the area of the circle with radius", r, "is:", str(pi * r ** 2))
```

---

For `main` method

- better use type than `eval` to get the type you need `x1 = float(input("enter x1"))`
- you miss one closing parenthesis

```
def main():
    x1 = float(input("enter x1"))
    y1 = float(input("enter y1"))
    x2 = float(input("enter x2"))
    y2 = float(input("enter y2"))
    print(((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1)) ** 2 ** (1 / 2))
    return ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1)) ** 2 ** (1 / 2)
```